# How to stop timer on loop with delay jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timer, delay

I have made loop which has delay every 10 sec. I set a timer for 10 sec. But its not stopping after 3 loop.... any ideas ? What I do wrong ? After 2 loop I am checking if it 3d loop I am clearing interval but as you can see it cant clear ? 
What I did so far: https://jsfiddle.net/56n720qm/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var i = 0;
var intervaltime;
var fiveMinutes = 10 * 1;
var display = document.querySelector('#timer');

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    intervaltime = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
function stopINT(){
    clearInterval(intervaltime);
}
function myLoop () {
    if(i > 0){time = 10000;}else{time=0;} //every 10 s.
    setTimeout(function () {
        //postFB(i);
        //alert(i);
        i++;
        if(i == 3){
            stopINT();
        }
        if (i <= 2) {
            startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
            myLoop();
        }
    }, time)
}
myLoop();
});
```

Comment: That is the abuse of timeout calls. You need to simplify your code and you probably don't need any loop. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting a new interval without clearing the first one, so at one point multiple intervals are running at the same time.

Add the line `clearInterval(intervaltime);` here to solve your problem.

```
  if (i <= 2) {
      clearInterval(intervaltime);
      startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
      myLoop();
  }
```

Check [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56n720qm/5/) out.

Also, you may want to consider changing the variable time from `10000` to `11000` to prevent the loop from finishing too soon.

Comment: Thanks missed it! :)

Comment: No problem, my pleasure :)